# Dynamic UILabel Based on String

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel

I have a `UILabel`. The text in the `UILabel` looks something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Website - example.com
YouTube - youtube.com/example
Twitter - twitter.com/example
Instagram - twitter.com/example
```

So this text is dynamic. I get the string from an API and the API contains a string like the one above. The first paragraph changes. It can be multiple paragraphs or anything. But the text with website links remains the same.

So basically, I want the label to only show the first part of the string. Then, whenever the user presses a button, it shows the whole string. I can't set the `numberOfLines` because the first part of the string changes. Is there any way to tell the label to only show text up to the

```
Website - example.com
YouTube - youtube.com/example
Twitter - twitter.com/example
Instagram - twitter.com/example
```

and then whenever the button is pressed, show the whole string?

I am using Swift 4.

Comment: How to determine whats the part that should be hidden for the first display?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried? It doesn't seem like that difficult a task; change the label's text when the button is tapped

Answer (score 0):

If it is formatted the same way and you know the element that separates the first string from the rest you can use the split function on the string to split the original str into substring.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
   @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
   let strFromApi = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \nWebsite - example.com \nYouTube - youtube.com/example \nTwitter - twitter.com/example \nInstagram - twitter.com/example"

   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.myLabel.text = getFirstSection(of: strFromApi)
   }

   func getFirstSection(of str: String) -> String
   {
       if let newStr = str.split(separator: "\n").first
       {
           return String(newStr)
       }
       return str
   }

   @IBAction func seeMoreAction(_ sender: UIButton)
   {
       self.myLabel.text = strFromApi
   }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea. But, the API does not return /n for new lines. It just returns the spaces, not the \n commands.

Comment: If you have access to the API and can change it then it might be easier to separate the first string from the links. Also in this case you would probably want to use a textview if you want the links to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the label's text into 2 parts: the `labelContent` that you get from the API, and the `labelFooter` which is the fixed string that you want to add to the label. Then you put property observers on them to update the `UILabel`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    /// The actual text that you get from the API
    var labelContent = "" {
        didSet {
            label.text = labelContent + (isExpanded ? labelFooter : "")
        }
    }

    /// The fixed footer string
    let labelFooter = """


    Website - example.com
    YouTube - youtube.com/example
    Twitter - twitter.com/example
    Instagram - twitter.com/example
    """

    /// Whether or not the label shows the footer
    var isExpanded = false {
        didSet {
            // A trick to trigger `didSet` on `labelContent`
            labelContent = { labelContent }()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Get this from the API
        labelContent = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

        // This is a trick to trigger to `didSet` observer on `isExpanded`
        isExpanded = { isExpanded }()
    }

    /// The action to show/hide the footer
    @IBAction func toggleExpand(_ sender: Any) {
        isExpanded = !isExpanded
    }
}
```